# How do I sort a list of objects based on key with conditional access in Javascript (and Flow)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flowtype

So I have a list of Items

```js
const items = this.props.complex_object?.items;
```

And I would like to sort these items based on a key. I would naturally like to perform the following

```js
const sortedItems = this.props.complex_object?.items.sort(
  (a, b) => a?.confidence > b?.confidence
);
```

Yet I am getting the following flow error.

```sh
Flow does not yet support method or property calls in optional chains.
```

Which somewhat makes sense because `items` is of the flow type `?Array<ItemType>`. Given the conditional nature of the existence of `Items`, I have tried to check for null and undefined

```js
var items = this.props.complex_object?.items;

if (items === null || items === undefined)
  items = [];

const sortedItems = items.sort((a, b) => a. confidence > b.confidence);

return (<Table items=sortedItems>);
```

Yet this doesn't alleviate the problem. Bottom line, how do I sort an array of optional objects?

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: You shouldn't use `>` operator in `compareFunction`: [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080785)

Comment: @adiga, good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that `props.complex_object` will always exist, you could do

```
var items = this.props.complex_object.items || [];
```

If `items` does not exist on your `complex_object` (undefined), or exists but has a value of `undefined` or `null`, then it will default it to the empty array.

Comment: Piggybacking on this, if you don't know if `complex_object` will exist you can do

`var items = (this.props.complex_object || {}).items || []`